# Как вывести среднее значение из столбца QTableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2, qtablewidget

Имеется таблица `QTableWidget`, как посчитать среднее значение определенного столбца?

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from untitled import Ui_MainWindow



class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.medium)

    def medium(self):
        pass
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**untitled.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Среднее значение"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Заполните столбец.
- Кликните по заголовку столбца.
- Нажмите кнопку "Среднее значение"

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from untitled import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Среднее значение"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
  
        self.indexColumn = None
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.medium)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().sectionClicked.connect(self._hh)

    def medium(self):
        rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()

        if not self.indexColumn:
            return
            
        _sum = 0    
        for row in range(rows):  
            item = self.tableWidget.item(row, self.indexColumn)
            item = item.text() if item else '0'
            _sum += float(item) if item else 0 
        
        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
            self, 
           'Результат', 
           f'Среднее значение столбца {self.indexColumn} = {_sum / rows}')         
        
    def _hh(self, index):
        self.indexColumn = index
   
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный ответ верен. Но, мне нужно заранее задать столбец в котором будет производится расчет (то есть пользователь его не выбирает).

Comment: @АндрейАлександров я так и сделал - кликните по заголовку нужного вам столбца и выполните расчет.

Comment: вы немного не поняли. Выбирать ни чего не надо, в коде написано 3 столбец значит и расчет по 3 столбцу, без выбора мной или еще кем то столбца.

Comment: @АндрейАлександров я не пойму вас, вы что не можете заменить строку `self.indexColumn = None` на строку `self.indexColumn = 2` ?

Comment: я могу. Просто это для того что бы ответ полностью соответствовал вопросу.

Comment: @АндрейАлександров где в вопросе написано то, о чем вы пишите в комментариях? The End.

Comment: этого не в вопросе. Но, так же нету  и про выбор. Так что с одной стороны вы правы.